# DataTables row.add() not working Ajax Server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I'm working on adding a new row in my datatable on button click. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="datatable-batches" class="table table-striped table-bordered forex-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Batch #</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Batch #</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var table;

$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    var batches_table = $('#datatable-batches').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
        "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('oss/admin/ajax_batches'); ?>",
                "type": "POST",
                data: {
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>' 
                },
           dataSrc: function ( json ) {
               if(json.csrf_token !== undefined) $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr("content", json.csrf_token);
               return json.data;
            }
        }
    });
$(function() {

    $('#new-batch').on('click', function(){
        $('#receiving-box').css('display', 'block');
        batches_table.row.add( ["3", "5", "2017-06-24 08:55:41"] ).draw();
    });
});

});

</script>
```

Both are in the same file. When I hit the button, only the 'draw' number is increased but the data is still the same.

I also copied and pasted the example table **[here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)** to make sure `row.add()` is working. Here's the **[debugger data](http://debug.datatables.net/ihafed)** for additional info.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Adding a row client side does not automagically update a table serverside (or whatever your serverside script is based on) You must add the row to the database yourself.

Comment: Yes, I just found out that it's just for client side. Thanks!